# Join two tables and save into third-sql

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join two tables.

### TableA

```
+-------------------+--------+
| wordA(primarykey) | countA |
+-------------------+--------+
| abc               |     25 |
| abcd              |     29 |
| abcde             |     45 |
+-------------------+--------+
```

---

### TableB

```
+-------------------+--------+
| wordB(primarykey) | countB |
+-------------------+--------+
| ab                |     10 |
| abc               |     40 |
| abcde             |     90 |
| abcdef            |     55 |
+-------------------+--------+
```

---

### Desired output:

### TableC

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  word  | countA | countB |
+--------+--------+--------+
| ab     |      0 |     10 |
| abc    |     25 |    40  |
| abcd   |     29 |      0 |
| abcde  |     45 |     90 |
| abcdef |      0 |     55 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

I want to insert values of the desired output in TableC. Please provide some code. I tried this but the problem which I am getting is that I am not able to merge wordA and wordB.

Comment: Show your query and result you get from it.

Comment: atleast just give the right RDBMS .. is it `MYSQL` or `SQL SERVER`

Comment: Is the SQL Server or MySql? Why are both tagged?

Comment: Can we see your query?

Comment: i am working on mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Edited for MYSQL ONLY**

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9deb2/22)

```
Insert into TableC(word , countA , countB)
Select IFNULL(TableA.wordA , TableB.wordB) as word ,
IFNULL(TableA.countA , 0) as countA , IFNULL(TableB.countB , 0) as countB 
from TableA LEFT join TableB on TableA.wordA = TableB.wordB
Union
Select IFNULL(TableA.wordA , TableB.wordB) as word ,
IFNULL(TableA.countA , 0) as countA , IFNULL(TableB.countB , 0)
from TableA RIGHT join TableB on TableA.wordA = TableB.wordB;
```

Comment: @user2986565 i think Mahmoud Gamal's answer is best for you and i am working on alternate answer without full outer join ... i might post it in 10 mins or so

Comment: i have understood it now. you have used both right and left join to make a full outer join. one more thing ifnull(a,b) works like this? if a is null then b is taken or when b is null then a is taken?

Comment: yes it works always ifnull works like this .. if first parameter is null then second paramater will be taken ..

Comment: @Linjhara how have u edited your user name ?? what i remember it was something like user... a while back .. and please accept my answer if you found it useful

Comment: Yes we can edit name. that user(something) was by default when i created my account.yes this post is helpful. do i need to click somewhere to accept.?

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO TableC
SELECT
  t.word,
  SUM(COALESCE(a.countA, 0)) AS CountA,
  SUM(COALESCE(b.countB, 0)) AS countB
FROM
(
   SELECT wordA AS word FROM tableA
   UNION
   SELECT wordB FROM tableB
) AS t
LEFT JOIN tableA AS a on t.word = a.wordA
LEFT JOIN tableB AS b on t.word = b.wordb
GROUP BY t.word
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed220/1)

This will give you:

```
|   WORD | COUNTA | COUNTB |
|--------|--------|--------|
|     ab |      0 |     10 |
|    abc |     25 |     40 |
|   abcd |     29 |      0 |
|  abcde |     45 |     90 |
| abcdef |      0 |     55 |
```

Comment: @Downvoter care to comment please what is the problem in my answer ???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Maybe it was to complex for the downvoter :) I upvoted it tho

Comment: @KayNelson - The problem isn't in the downvote, but I just want to know what is the problem to fix it or delete the answer, its OK to get downvote, but for a reason.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal .. thx ... just a side question  -- why MYSQL lacks this much in simple sql task like .. no direct support of full join .. no direct support of isnull .. wrong implementation of group by and so on .. i know there are work around but mysql sud work on this

Comment: @Dhaval Yes, there is a lot of strange things, the most one is the `group by`. I don't know really it is just made this way.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal this answer solved this and some other problems also which i was facing. thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

```
Insert into TableC
select wordA as word, countA, 0 as countB from TableA 
where wordA not in (select wordB from tableB)
union
select wordB as word, 0 as countA, countB from TableB
where wordB not in (select wordA from tableA)
union
select wordA as word, countA, countB 
from TableA join TableB on wordA=wordB
order by word asc
```

SQL fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9deb2/10)

Comment: Just add ORDER BY WORD ASC also :)

Comment: thanks..this query worked but how will i save the result in TableC?

Comment: @KayNelson Done! Thnx.

Comment: @user2986565 With the `Insert Into` clause