# update table if not present then insert

Tags: mysql

this question is in continuation with my previous question.

[join 2 tables and save into third-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948334/join-2-tables-and-save-into-third-sql)

this time, situation is something like this

```
TableA
+-------------------+--------+
| wordA(primarykey) | countA |
+-------------------+--------+
| pqr               |      5 |
| abcd              |     20 |
| pqrs              |     45 |
+-------------------+--------+

TableB
+-------------------+--------+
| wordB(primarykey) | countB |
+-------------------+--------+
| pq                |     10 |
| abc               |     10 |
| pqrs              |     10 |
| abcdef            |      5 |
+-------------------+--------+
```

This time TableC already have these tuples in it. If any word which is already present in TableC, then its count will be incremented by the value of TableA or TableB. if not then that new word is add into it. It is something like we are updating the table and inserting if update is not done.

```
TableC(before query)
+--------+--------+--------+
|  word  | countA | countB |
+--------+--------+--------+
| ab     |      0 |     10 |
| abc    |     25 |     40 |
| abcd   |     29 |      0 |
| abcde  |     45 |     90 |
| abcdef |      0 |     55 |
+--------+--------+--------+

Desired output:
TableC(after query)
+--------+--------+--------+
|  word  | countA | countB |
+--------+--------+--------+
| ab     |      0 |     10 |
| abc    |     25 |     50 |
| abcd   |     49 |      0 |
| abcde  |     45 |     90 |
| abcdef |      0 |     60 |
| pq     |      0 |     10 |
| pqr    |      5 |      0 |
| pqrs   |     45 |     10 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Using PHP ? or any other language

Comment: i am working on mysql

Comment: Do you know mysql procedures ? They allow conditional statements like if and so on.

Comment: @ChinnuR i am working java with mysql actually. but that java part is not a problem for me right now. if any combination of one or two query works  and gives the right solution. Things would become easier otherwise i would need to seperate out words which are present from the words which are not present. that would be quite inefficient.

Comment: @ArlaudAgbePierre   No i dont know about it. please tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can do it in one query if `TableC.Word` is a PRIMARY KEY using [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9009c/1)

```
INSERT INTO TableC(Word,CountA,CountB)

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT Word,SUM(CountA) as Ca,SUM(CountB) as Cb 
FROM
(
  SELECT WordA as Word,CountA, 0 as CountB FROM TableA
   UNION ALL
  SELECT WordB as Word,0 as CountA, CountB FROM TableB
) T GROUP BY Word  
) T1  

ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE CountA = CountA+T1.Ca,CountB = CountB+T1.Cb
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**  Try this may help you.

```
INSERT INTO 'your previos query'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  countA = coutnA +1
```